# Memory handling by ConstantArray

Tags: memory, packed-arrays

I noticed the following issue when using `ConstantArray`:

```
a = ConstantArray[0., {10000, 100}];
ByteCount[a]
(* 8000152 *)
```

Then I set:

```
a[[1,1]] = 1;
ByteCount[a]
(* 25040080 *)
```

So to be sure my array will not expand in memory without reason I must multiply each element I want to change by 1.0

Is there another way (more efficient) to ensure I won't change the type of data by accident? `Real` to `Integer` shouldn't be a problem...

Comment: Probably the array was initially packed because it had only one type of data and when another type was introduced was unpacked. Try adding `1.` instead of `1` and see what happens.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not because of `ConstantArray`, but is because of unpacking due to mixing different types. In short, [packed arrays](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3496/5) are more memory efficient and can contain only data of one type (`Integer`, `Real` or `Complex`) in regular lists (any dimension). That way, *Mathematica* need not store the type of each element.

```
a = ConstantArray[0., {10000, 100}];
Developer`PackedArrayQ@a
(* True *)

ByteCount[a]
(* 8000152 *)
```

When you add `1` (an `Integer`) to a list of `Real`s, you cause the list to be unpacked, which increases memory usage (since the type of each element is stored).

```
On["Packing"];
a[[1, 1]] = 1;
```

> During evaluation of In[...]:= Developer`FromPackedArray::punpack1: Unpacking array with dimensions {10000,100}. >>

```
ByteCount[a]
(* 25037600 *)

Developer`PackedArrayQ@a
(* False *)
```

Try assigning a `Real` instead:

```
Clear@a
a = ConstantArray[0., {10000, 100}];
Developer`PackedArrayQ@a
(* True *)

a[[1, 1]] = 1.;
Developer`PackedArrayQ@a
(* True *)

ByteCount[a]
(* 8000152 *)
```

Comment: For packed arrays the behavior is arguably simpler than in other cases. Since `ConstantArray` can also return an array of pointers to the element, and given that `ByteCount` doesn't take into account which objects are real and which are just references to others, the results could get really confusing.